Proposal about being more detailed and precise in the title of questions
Now that the site has finally gone public, I would recommend everyone (if you agree, of course) to be more detailed and precise in the title of questions.
I mean, the site is intended for the creation of a collection of quality questions and answers available to everyone on the Web. If my question is such that people don't notice it from its title, it won't get much visibility.
I would suggest to make the general aim of the question clear from its title.
For example, if I want to ask information about a particular idiom, a title like "idiom" is not effective, in my opinion. It would be good to have something like "origin of the idiom".
I hope the idea is clear.

I've seen your recent edits and I agree 100%. Title should be meaningful and specific in summarizing the content of the question.
I also kind of dislike the titles in the form

"X" vs "Y"

as they look like a horror B movie.
For instance I think they could better rephrased into something like

When is it more appropriate to use "X" in place of "Y"?

or 

Is "X" acceptable as a replacement of "Y"?

